# Run Android Studio after installation (and other programs)

Tags: launcher, android, installed-programs, android-studio

I downloaded Android Studio from the official website, started the installer with the terminal (studio.sh) it installed completely, wrote some lines of code, closed Android Studio, now I don't know how I can open it again. the studio.sh just starts the setup wizard again and I also can't find the directory where it could be installed in.

So where are the installed programs at and how can I run them?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

#### Short answer

You need to run it via the `studio.sh`, every time, as that is the startup script.

#### Long answer

It will not truly 'install'. It is kind of an annoyance for first time users, but it is truly a stand-alone package, it will drop the SDK in your `/home` and you need the `android-studio` and `jdk1.8.0_45` folders at a fixed location.

First, you need to set the `JAVA_HOME` path in your `/etc/environment` or `~/.bashrc` configuration to the `jdk1.8.0_45` folder before it will run.

After setting your `JAVA_HOME`, run `studio.sh` again and it will boot the IDE. Then at the menu, hit the **Configure** button then hit **Create Desktop Entry**. You should now have a start menu icon, and desktop icon which you can easily use.

Next time you boot and create a project it should download the SDK required for building.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If i click on 'Create Desktop Entry' in Android Studio, it doesn't do anything. Do I have to configure something else?

Comment: Try logging out and back in, seemed to resolve my issue.

Comment: In Studio 2.2 the `Create Desktop Entry...` menu option is under the `Tools` menu option. There is no `Configure` option.

Answer (score 28):

Just wanted to let you know that you don't have to run the install every time. Here is how I installed Android Studio, and how I run it from my applications menu.

At the Android Studio start screen below, click on configure then create desktop entry.

[image: Screenshot of start screen]

Now you should have a shortcut in your applications menu.

Comment: this should be considerer as the best answer

Comment: definetly best answer !

Comment: Keep support this and upboat.

Comment: My version doesn't give you the option to create desktop entry (Arctic Fox 2020.3.1)

Answer (score 18):

Use these commands in the Terminal

```
cd /opt/android-studio/bin
./studio.sh
```

Answer (score 12):

You can create a file "studio.desktop" in /usr/share/applications with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Android Studio
Comment=Android Studio
Exec=/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
Icon=/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Development
```

Assuming you put android-studio in /opt, this allows you to launch from the application launcher. Otherwise adjust to your android-studio folder location.

Answer (score 5):

**To add shortcut command for Terminal to open Android-Studio::**

To run from Terminal create a file named **studio** inside `/bin` folder and write following contents inside the file named **studio**.

```
cd /opt/android-studio/bin 
./studio.sh
```

Then type in terminal `cd /bin` and `chmod +x studio`.

Now, if you want to open it just type **studio** in Terminal.

**To add shortcut Application Icon to open Android-Studio::**

Create file inside `/usr/share/applications` named **studio.desktop** with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Android Studio
Comment=Android Studio
Exec=/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
Icon=/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Development
```

After that you can Android Studio Application launcher is added automatically.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few steps to run Android Studio by clicking the Launcher icon.

1. Execute your studio.sh file located in bin folder of Android Studio,
   like my Android Studio is located in Downloads (`~/Downloads/android-studio/bin`). You are in bin folder, now run this command: `./studio.sh`

**In Ubuntu** 
System-Product-Name:~/Downloads/android-studio/bin$ ./studio.sh

2. Android Studio will be launched using the above command, next close the project using *File* -> *Close Project* from Android Studio,
   then you'll find this screen:

   [image]

   At the Android Studio start screen below, click on *Configure* then create a desktop entry.
3. Finally you have to lock Android Studio to Launcher icon
   when you press right-click on Android Studio (on the left of the screen) click *Lock to Launcher* or *Add to Favorites*.

Answer (score 0):

After you start Android Studio for first time from the terminal with the command /path/to/android-studio/studio.sh there will be shown an icon on your launcher. Just right click it and choose "lock to launcher" and that's it - now you can start it from there